# Is this regex is correct for validating email ID

Tags: javascript, html

If there are any changes tell me...
It should accept general mail ids
"xyz@adaf@fa.com" should not accept
"xyzadaf@fa.com","xyz@ad.co.in" should accept

```js
function checkEmail(){
  var emailFormat = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+[@]{1}[.]{1}[a-z]{2,3}[.]*[a-z]{0,3}$/;
  var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var emailStatus = emailFormat.exec(email);
  if(emailStatus == "true"){
 alert("success");
  }
  else(emailStatus == "false"){
 alert("Try again");
   }
}
```

Comment: is this code have any problem?

Comment: yeah it's not giving any output

Comment: Try this `[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}`

Answer (score 0):

I have changed your code as follows and it seems it is working fine. Please check.

```js
function checkEmail(){
debugger;
 var emailFormat = /^(([^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/i;
 var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
 var emailStatus = emailFormat.exec(email);
 if(emailStatus)
  alert("valid email id");
 else
  alert("Not valid");
}
checkEmail();
```

```html
<input type="text" id="email" value="xyzad@af@fa.com" />
```

You can also see the fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sibeeshvenu/yfghq9p5/1/).